# mail parsing subject encoding

Tags: php

i am using this class https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser

to parse emails

class is fully of problems

today i found big one

i have just recieved message from gmail now

message subject is encoded, and i can't decode it!

```
Subject: =?windows-1256?B?4+XjIMzPx/AgyO3kx8ogys7VIMfhz+bj7eQ=?=
From: Some One <someone@gmail.com>
```

i can't decode the subject..

any one know a better mail parsing class?

IF NO: How can i decode this subject?

Comment: i suspect the class is fine its just an issue with your usage of it (which you haven't shown)

Comment: Don't know if this is a problem with the class or how you're using it, but I can vouch for the functioning state of [PEAR Mail_mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/redirected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to manually convert to another encoding:

```
$x = "=?windows-1256?B?4+XjIMzPx/AgyO3kx8ogys7VIMfhz+bj7eQ=?=";
@iconv('windows-1256', 'UTF-8', base64_decode($x));
print_r($x);
```

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php for more info.

Comment: back, i tryied this solution 3 hours ago and it works fine, this code is exactly like mine

Answer (score 1):

more flexible:

```
$x = "=?windows-1256?B?4+XjIMzPx/AgyO3kx8ogys7VIMfhz+bj7eQ=?=";
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($x);
```

check http://php.net/mb_decode_mimeheader